# Scope Resolution Operator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have read the following syntax. I have no idea why scope resolution operator is used in it.

```
class XyzFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var adapter: ChatAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (!::adapter.isInitialized) { <-- This one
            adapter = ChatAdapter(this, arrayListOf())
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know what is `::` in `if (!::adapter.isInitialized) {` statement.

Comment: FYI, trying to compile this in Kotlin <1.2 gives a pretty descriptive error message of what it is. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html

Answer (score 6):

`::` is a short form for `this::` in Kotlin.

`::` is a operator to creates a member reference or a class reference. For example,

```
class Test {        
    fun foo() {

    }

    fun foo2(value: Int) {

    }

    fun bar() {
        val fooFunction = ::foo
        fooFunction.invoke()  // equals to this.foo()
        val foo2Function = ::foo2
        foo2Function.invoke(1)  // equals to this.foo2(1)
        val fooFunction2 = Test::foo
        val testObject = Test()
        fooFunction2.invoke(this) // equals to this.foo()
        fooFunction2.invoke(testObject) // equals to testObject.foo()
    }
}
```

This is mainly used in reflection and passing function.

Comment: Is it still called a "scope resolution" operator? Couldn't see that name anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @VishnuHaridas No, because it never call like that. [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11) may be what you needed. Also, you should ask a new question instead of writing comment.